# Execute statement only once in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I'm running a periodic task on Celery that executes the same code once every 3 minutes. If a condition is True, an action is performed (a message is sent), but I need that message to be sent only once.

The ideal would be that that message, if sent, it could not be sent in the next 24 hours (even though the function will keep being executed every 3 minutes), and after those 24 hours, the condition will be checked again and message sent again if still True. How can I accomplish that with Python? I put here some code:

```
if object.shussui:
    client.conversation_start({
        'channelId': 'x',
        'to': 'user',
        'type': 'text',
        'content': {
            'text': 'body message')
        }
    })
```

Here the condition is being checked, and if `shussui` is `True` the `client.start_conversation` sends a message.

Comment: So create another condition that tracks time.

Comment: The common way is to persist an unique message identifier in a database, along with the timestamp of the moment it was sent. When a message is about to be sent, you just have to search for its identifier in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep the last time the message was sent and check that 24 hours have passed:

```py
from time import time
lastSent = None
if object.shussui and (not lastSent or (time() - lastSent) >= 24 * 60 * 60):
    client.conversation_start({
        'channelId': 'x',
        'to': 'user',
        'type': 'text',
        'content': {
            'text': 'body message')
        }
    })
    lastSent = time()
```

Comment: maybe is there a typo in the 'toSencond()' function?

Comment: @Jim damnit.... it should be `total_seconds()`, of course. Not sure what I was thinking. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Also I'm guessing there should be a ')' after the last 60 if the syntax is correct?

Comment: @Jim yup... fixed. Not my best showing

Comment: No worries, thank you very much, I'm testing it right now. I'll come back to you

Comment: As you're just using seconds, why use datetime at all.  Wouldn't `time.time` be easier?  `datetime` is about the Gregorian calendar, which seems irrelevant here.

Comment: @SamMason good point! old habits die hard. Edited to use `time.time`.

Comment: While I personally like the use of clear flag values / initial values like `lastSent = None`, using a zero-ish initial value like `last_sent = datetime(1900, 1, 1)` for datetime or `last_sent = 0` for time.time would simplify the if-condition for time elapsed.

Comment: It works, thank you very much. As a celery task is a function I had to declare the last_time variable outside the function and call it with the global tag for it to work. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding a check for time of last execution, as done in [Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75046752/1431750), if you have multiple workers, you should **get and store the last execution time in a central shared location**. For example, whichever message broker you're using with celery, or to a database.

The key for `last_sent` should also include a deterministic signature to match unique messages and/or user ids; or whatever criteria you need. With the value being a datetime object or an int/float for seconds (for `time.time()`)

If you don't store this in a central/shared location, then when a different worker/instance gets the next task for the same message, it would end up getting resent immediately. Because the previous `last_sent` would be stored only on the previous worker's memory and the current worker would have not have that updated value.

Examples of how you could store the `last_sent` info:

- In Redis, the *keys* could be in the form `last_sent:user:1234:msg:9876` with the value as a `datetime.datetime` or `time.time`. Here `9876` is the hash for  the message, like `hash('hello')`. Don't store the message itself. *[works for multiple worker instances]*

  ```py
  import redis

  client = redis.Redis()
  key = 'last_sent:user:1234:msg:9876'
  last_sent = client.get(key) or '0'  # missing/None will be converted to 0
  if object.shussui and time.time() - int(last_sent) > 24 * 60 * 60:
      last_sent = client.set(key, time.time())
      client.conversation_start({...})
  ```

  It's possible to do this as an [**atomic operation**](https://redis.io/commands/set/#options) which avoids race-conditions. Use `set` with a 24 hour expiration since messages would need to be sent after that period or if it's not present Redis. This can be used to just store some arbitrary string and use its existence in redis as a flag:

  ```py
  ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60
  key = 'last_sent:user:1234:msg:9876'

  # set a new flag only if it doesn't exist, with a 24-hour expiration
  status = client.set(key, 'A', nx=True, ex=ONE_DAY)

  # None implies it was present in redis so 24 hours have not yet passed
  if object.shussui and status is not None:
      client.conversation_start({...})
  ```

  The `if object.shussui and status is not None` can be simplified to `if object.shussui and status`.
- In a DB, it could be a table `last_sent` with `user_id`, `msg_hash`, `sent_at`. *[works for multiple worker instances]*
- In a dictionary with the user_id and the msg *hash*. *[only works for single worker instances since this is stored in memory]*:

  ```py
  last_sent = {
      (1234, msg1): ..., # <datetime or time>
      (1234, msg2): ..., # another message
      (5678, msg1): ..., # another user, same message
      ... # etc.
  }
  ```

Also, based on your needs and situation, you need to decide how you want to handle race conditions. Like same message triggers twice in a row and before the first one has updated 'last_sent'.

Comment: This is a great and a very informative answer, I will definetly go through it in very detail, thank you very much!